# How can I create a horizontal set of social media links in the footer of a Blogger site

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm trying to setup a Blogger site and would like to include a horizontal set of social media links in the footer.  I can add image widgets in Blogger that are linked, but when I add more than one they appear vertically and left-justified.  I tried wrapping the widgets I wanted in `<div>` tags and using `css` to alter their positioning, but Blogger wouldn't let me save the raw code saying:

> All widgets must be wrapped with a `<section>` tag.

Has anyone else had this issue and if so how did you over come it?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding each link separately with Blogger’s image widget, insert a single HTML/Java widget with code similar to the chunk below with the link and image path references updated to the ones you plan to use.

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="link1"><img src="img_src1”></a></li>
<li><a href="link2"><img src="img_src2”></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then go into the “Theme” panel and click “Customize”.  In the new screen choose the “Advanced” tab and scroll down to “Add CSS”. Paste the below code to be added.  The result should be a horizontal list of linked images in your footer.

```
#menu ul{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu li{
  display: inline;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Note: you can change the spacing by changing `margin` if desired.

Also, since you mentioned you were using the Image widget which allows you to upload images, if you need your own images hosted you can still use the Image widget for this.  Upload your image into an Image widget and place it on your home page.  Go to your website and right-click on the image and choose "Open in New Tab".  Copy the URL and place it into the `html` list you're creating to house your social media links.  You can then tun off the visibility of the Image widget and Blogger will still host the image.